# How to call another function or another process without waiting for a response efficiently

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing

In Python on Linux, I have a function that calls itself over and over. This function doesn't need to return a response to the calling function because things are recorded to files (in a tempfs filesystem, in ram).

The below is a very simple example of what I'm doing.

```
import signal
import subprocess
from sys import argv, exit

# Ignore sigterm.
signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)


def main(arg1,arg2)
    # < A lot of compute-heavy stuff here >
    # Call myself again with some new arguments.
    subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python","/myscript.py", arg1, arg2])
    # < More compute-heavy stuff >
    exit(0)

# Entry point of the script.
main(str(argv[1]),str(argv[2]))
```

The above runs and then creates a new process totally detached from the old. I'm ignoring some signals so the parent exits. This prevents infinite zombie processes from piling up. When I start up this script, it launches itself again with some new arguments, and then again, and again, endlessly.

This is working. It's delivering the desired outcome, but it's really slow. The processes are taking around 0.4 seconds to complete and I think a lot of that is process spin-up time and not actual processing time.

Is there a better/faster way to do this? I read a lot about double forking in Linux, I'm not sure if that's the solution as it'd be creating more processes. Also was thinking a lot on the multiprocessing module but I'm unsure how to use it to endlessly call the same function from within the same function over and over without crashing due to recursion.

Comment: Do these functions access the same files? If not, maybe the threading module is an option?

Comment: On the other hand: Why bother with multi-processing or threading at all? It sounds like just a regular recursive function: the function input is depending on the previous output. And if it's not, you could create a bunch of worker processes in advance and initialize them with different arguments.

Comment: @pktl2k If I use recursion, I eventually run out of ram. Because this runs without end. The recursion would never unwind itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you can test this. replace this line:

```
    subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python","/myscript.py", arg1, arg2])
```

with this one:

```
    subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python","/myscript.py","&", "disown", arg1, arg2])
```

if it doesn't work try os library like below:

```
import os
os.system( "<your command> & disown " )
```